# If and else statement in Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript

want to run this javascript when there the button is clicked, if errors on the form check if statement and stop, if no errors execute the else statement......

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $('#continueToAttachments').on('click', function() { //on click button
            if ($("#cevent").valid() = false) { // if errors stop the user from moving forward
                return;
            } else { // expecting this to run if there are no errors in the form
                $('#Event-Information').removeClass('w--tab-active');
                $('#Attachments').addClass('w--tab-active');
                $('#Event-Information-Tab').removeClass('w--current');
                $('#Attachments-Tab').addClass('w--current');
            }
        });
      });
```

Comment: What is `.valid()`? What is going wrong? What should be happening?

Comment: A single equals assigns a value. A double or triple equals checks for sameness. Your if statement will always return true.

Comment: The `= false` seems suspicious. Probably You need `== false` or `=== false`.

Comment: On a related note, if you don't care whether the value is `false` or falsey, you can use `if (!$("#cevent").valid()) { ...` (the logical NOT operator, `!`) to do this comparison. Also, because your `if` block is just a `return` statement, you can skip the `else` wrapping the rest of your code entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a value is equal another you should use `==` or `===` to check if the variables are the same type too. `=` is for attribution.

```
if ($("#cevent").valid() == false)
```

Comment: Thank you buddy! New to coding..